# putting arrays together grouped

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I'm a little struggeling with results from a database fetch

lets say i have some rows

```
   array('id'=>1, 'surname'=>'rossi', 'name'=>'mario', 'group'=>'admin'), 
   array('id'=>2, 'surname'=>'rossi', 'name'=>'giovanni', 'group'=>'user'), 
   array('id'=>3, 'surname'=>'verdi', 'name'=>'luigi', 'group'=>'user'), 
   array('id'=>4, 'surname'=>'verdi', 'name'=>'franco', 'group'=>'guest'), 
   array('id'=>5, 'surname'=>'bianchi', 'name'=>'mario', 'group'=>'guest')
```

now what do I have to do to put these 5 rows into a grouped array?

example:

```
user = array(
   array('id'=>2, 'surname'=>'rossi', 'name'=>'giovanni', 'group'=>'user'), 
   array('id'=>3, 'surname'=>'verdi', 'name'=>'luigi', 'group'=>'user'))
guest = array(
   array('id'=>4, 'surname'=>'verdi', 'name'=>'franco', 'group'=>'guest'), 
   array('id'=>5, 'surname'=>'bianchi', 'name'=>'mario', 'group'=>'guest')) 
admin = array(
   array('id'=>1, 'surname'=>'rossi', 'name'=>'mario', 'group'=>'admin'))
```

Comment: How are you generating the array? If it's from a database, you can append each row to an empty array using `$arr[] = $row`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// get query result
$result = mysql_query(...);

// prepare the target array
// it will hold user groups having group name as key
// eg. "user" => Array(), "guest" => Array()
$users = Array();

// whlile fetching rows from the result, add each row into $row["group"] key of target
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   $users[$row["group"]][] = $row;

// free the mysql result
mysql_free_result($result);
```

**Update**: There is no real need to define the keys in the target `$user` variable. to make code readable and manageable it is enough to comment on the general structure.

Comment: Prepping the array is redundant, as each distinctive `group` will do that automatically in the while loop.

Comment: @MikePurcell it will, but the same way that i like to define variables before using them, i think it makes code more readable. especially when you know form the beginning what the grouping looks like.

Comment: wow, thanks, that was fast and very helpful, finally, after about 2 hours of trial and error :)

Comment: @Poncha: So if you add another group to the database, you are going to remember to update the code, push it to production?

Comment: Well, you're right, i could've just put up a comment on the definition stating the structure ;) Hang on, i'll update the answer...

Comment: you forgot the s on users in the while loop ;) :p